# Client-server Python app on Heroku: how does client communicate with the server?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, fastapi, plotly-dash

I've been searching for the solution quite long and haven't found an answer yet.
I have a ML project, where based on user's parameters I predict his/her income. T

I have a Dash app, where the page layout is stored. That is a simple form to get data from user. I also have another python file with FastAPI, where all the calculations and predictions are done.
The idea is the following: user fills the form, clicks Submit button and then request with the data goes to FastAPI, where the prediction is done, and then on the same page without any redirections I show the prediction and a shap graph (doesn't matter, though). It perfectly works on my local computer, when I have to call the server like:

```
response = requests.get(
                    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict_induvidual_income/',
                    params={
                        'age': age_input, 
                        'workclass': workclass_input, 
                        'education': education_input,
                        'marital_status': marital_satus_input,
                        'occupation': occupation_input,
                        'relationship': relationschip_input,
                        'ethnic_group': ethnic_group_input,
                        'sex': sex_input,
                        'country': country_input,
                        'capital_gain': capital_gain_input,
                        'capital_loss': capital_loss_input,
                        'hours_per_week': hpw_input
                    }
```

All my troubles begin when I want to deploy this to heroku (or any other platform). How should I store this project? Should that be 2 separate heroku projects, like https://my-client.herokuapp.com/ with a form and a Submit button, and https://my-server.herokuapp.com/ , which does all the calculations, and put this link instead of `127.0.0.1:8000`? Or I can somehow have one link with a form and do the calculations under the hood?

To simplify the problem, let's pretend it's is a simple program, that adds 2 numbers. So there's 2 number inputs and a submit button, that sends a request to server with these 2 numbers as parameters. In return it gets a json file with a `sum` key and the result of calculation as a value.

it would look smth like that:

1. dash app with layout

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import requests

#create app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server

#create layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    className = 'body',
    children = [
        html.Div(
            className='questionnaire',
            children = [
                html.Div(
                    children = [
                        dcc.Input(
                            className = 'num_input',
                            id = 'num1_input',
                            type="number",
                            debounce=True
                        ),
                        dcc.Input(
                            className = 'num_input',
                            id = 'num2_input',
                            type="number",
                            debounce=True
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
        html.Div(
            className='submit-button',
            children=[dbc.Button('Submit', id='submit-btn', size = 'lg', color ='success', n_clicks=0)]
        ),
        html.Div(
            className = 'output',
            children = [
                html.H3(id='output_text'),
            ]
        )
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('output_text', 'children'),
    Input('submit-btn', 'n_clicks'),
    State('num1_input', 'value'),
    State('num2_input', 'value')
)
def update_output_div(n_clicks, num1_input, num2_input):
    if n_clicks >0 :
        response = requests.get(
            'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_numbers/',
            params={
                'num1': num1_input, 
                'num2': num2_input
            }, 
            timeout=10
        )
        json_response = response.json()
        sum_of_numbers = json_response.get('result')
        
        return sum_of_numbers
    else:
        return ['there must be 2 numbers']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

2. FastAPI

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

# define target function
def sum_numbers(num1: int, num2: int):
   sum = num1 + num2
   return {'result': sum}

@app.get("/add_numbers/")
def sum_numbers_result(num1: int, num2: int):
    return sum_numbers(num1, num2)
```

I haven't found any solution, so I had to refuse the client-server architecture and do all computations on client side :(

Comment: As I said, there are no errors because I do not understand what I should set instead of localhost in a client (dash) app here:

response = requests.get(
                    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_request',
                    params={'some_key': some_value}

Comment: Did you try it with the URL to your second application? i.e. `https://my-server.herokuapp.com/add_numbers/`? What happens if you open that URL directly in your browser? (without going through the dash app - it's also important to point out that in this case `dash` is a Python library, not shorthand for dashboard :-)

Comment: so that should be 2 applications: server and client separately? and I first create a server on heroku and then deploy client with the link to this server on heroku, right?